# scss is not detecting id and classes?

Tags: html, sass, webpack-5

This is a very rare issue I've never seen before.
Actually I've just set up a minimal html-scss template with Webpack 5,
but for whatever reason is only applying styles to html and body tags.
Id's and classes are not recognized, I have no idea what's going on.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ'S</a></li>
          <li><a href="">عربى</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <button>Log out &#9657;</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here my index.scss:

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'scaffolding';
```

_variables.scss

```
$font-size: 62.5%;
$font-family: verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;
$font-color: #76645d;
$white: #fff;
$turquoise: #199fd9;
$indigo: #283a97;
$orange: #f08429;
$light-gray: #f2f2f2;

$background-color: $light-gray;
$page-max-width: 95.2rem;
$page-min-width: 57.6rem;
```

_scaffolding.scss

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: $font-size;
}

body {
  background: $background-color;
  color: $font-color;
  font-family: $font-family;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

#root {
  background-color: $white;
  max-width: $page-max-width;
  min-width: $page-min-width;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

In Chrome console only html and body styles shows up and
no #root element at all.

Please help me to know what's the issue behind this.

Thank you!

Comment: https://codepen.io/developersbeat/pen/oNWwXWP

Your code is working. there must be some other issue in your file. May be you haven't connected your sass/scss file properly

Comment: I finally could resolve it. The css-loader changes id and class names when modules option is enabled, so you need a little more of configuration to get it work. Here is the CSS-Loader docs => https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/blob/master/README.md#object-2